# Child not rerendered when prop set with useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, mui-datatable

I have a situation where I have parent (`App`) and child (`MUIDatatable`) component. The child is a datatable which accepts `columns` prop describing columns structure along with defining custom render function for one of them. In this custom render function I create a button instance for which `disabled` state should depend on parent's state, on `buttonsDisabled` value which is set via `useState()` hook. Up to this point it works fine, but when I also change the `columns` prop using `useState()`, the rerender does not trigger anymore when changing `buttonsDisabled` value. The code looks like this:

```
  const App = () => {
  const [buttonsDisabled, setButtonsDisabled] = useState(false);

  const tableData = {
    columns: [
      { name: "name", label: "Name", options: {} },
      {
        name: "action",
        label: "Action",
        options: {
          customBodyRender: v => (
            <button disabled={buttonsDisabled}>button</button>
          )
        }
      }
    ],
    data: [["A", null], ["B", null], ["C", null], ["D", null]]
  };

  const btnOnClick = () => {
    setButtonsDisabled(true);
  };

  /***** discussed part of code *****/
  const [columns] = useState(tableData.columns); // if we use this, buttons are not disabled
  //const columns = tableData.columns; // if we use this, buttons are properly disabled
  /**********************************/

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={btnOnClick}>DISABLE BUTTONS</button>
      <MUIDataTable title="title" data={tableData.data} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

It's also available at codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/muidatatables-custom-toolbar-cy4vg

The code that I prepared is a stripped version of my original one so it might not make a lot of sense, but it limits the code to the bare minimum, just to be able to reproduce the problem.

What I can't understand is why does using `useState` to modify `columns` value would prevent specified `customBodyRender` function from being triggered when `buttonsDisabled` value is changed, whereas setting it via simple assignment works just fine. In both cases it's still the reference to the same array after all. I believe this is some simple concept that I'm missing, but I would appreciate some help in pointing out what's that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your initial `columns` state, your `customBodyRender` function has access to the outer function's `buttonsDisabled` variable (see: [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)), which is defaulted to `false`. Once initialized, your `columns` variable is stored in your state, and the `buttonsDisabled` variable inside `customBodyRender` will continue to reference the original value from the outer function.

Would it be possible for you to instead pass `buttonsDisabled` into your `MUIDataTable` table component, and perhaps pass it as an argument to the `customBodyRender` function?

```
customBodyRender: (v, disabled) => (
  <button disabled={disabled}>button</button>
)
```

Comment: Note that if you recreate `tableData.columns` as you do in your post, `customBodyRender` can directly access the most up to date value of `buttonsDisabled` in the outer function.